# Bug with animations in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

In Firefox, this code works perfectly, but in Chrome all the content in this section is not displayed after the the last active item was closed. 5th item, if you go over all the items in the order.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2mj68Lo4/2/).

JS:

```
var markets = {
    radius: 250, // in px

    init: function () {
        $('.markets-item a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var market = $(this).parent('.markets-item');

            if (market.hasClass('active')) {
                markets.showMarkets(market);
                return false;
            }

            markets.showItem(market);

            return false;
        });

        $('#markets-wrap').css('min-height', $('#markets-wrap').height() + 'px');
    },

    showItem: function (market) {
        $('.markets-item').removeClass('active fadeIn').removeAttr('style');

        market.addClass('active');

        var notActivedItems = $('.markets-item:not(.active)');

        notActivedItems.addClass('fadeOut');

        $('.markets-item:not(.active):last').one(animatedend, function () {
            var offset = market.position();

            market.data('top', offset.top)
                .data('left', offset.left)
                .css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: offset.top + 'px',
                left: offset.left + 'px'
            })
                .animate({
                top: 0,
                left: 7
            }, 0, function () {
                notActivedItems.hide().removeClass('fadeOut');
                markets.showSubmarkets(market);

                var img = market.children('a').children('img');

                market.data('src', img.attr('src'));
                img.attr('src', 'images/icons/back.png');
            });
        });
    },

    showMarkets: function (market) {
        market.children('a').children('img').attr('src', market.data('src'));

        var submarkets = $('.submarket:visible');

        if (0 === submarkets.length) {
            markets._show(market);
            return;
        }

        submarkets.addClass('fadeOut');

        $('.submarket:visible:last').one(animatedend, function () {
            submarkets.removeClass('fadeOut').hide();
            markets._show(market);
        });
    },

    _show: function (market) {
        var notActivedItems = $('.markets-item:not(.active)');

        market.animate({
            top: market.data('top') + 'px',
            left: market.data('left') + 'px'
        }, 0, function () {
            market.removeAttr('style').removeClass('active');


            notActivedItems.show().addClass('fadeIn').one(animatedend, function () {
                $(this).removeClass('fadeIn');
            });
        });
    },

    showSubmarkets: function (market) {
        var items = market.children('.submarket');

        if (0 === items.length) return;

        var delta = Math.PI / 3 / items.length;
        var x = 0,
            y = 0,
            angle = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            items.eq(i).css({
                left: markets.radius * Math.cos(angle) + 'px',
                top: markets.radius * Math.sin(angle) + 'px',
                display: 'list-item'
            })
                .addClass('animated fadeIn')
                .one(animatedend, function () {
                $(this).removeClass('fadeIn');
            });
            angle += delta;
        }
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<section id="markets">
    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="text-center">KEY SECTORS</h3>
        <div class="row text-center" id="markets-wrap">
            <ul class="markets-container">
                <li class="markets-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/icons/food.png" class="img-responsive"><br>
                        Food and Drink
                    </a>                    
                    <div class="submarket">Hot and Cold food containers/boxes</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Hot and Cold drink cups</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Bags (paper, non-woven, fabric)</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Postal boxes</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Printed ribbon</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Sticky labels</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Grease proof paper</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Custom retail packaging</div>
                </li>
                <li class="markets-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/icons/fashion.png" class="img-responsive"><br>
                        Fashion and Jewellery
                    </a>                    
                    <div class="submarket">Retail boxes</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Luxury jewellery boxes</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Exclusive souvenir boxes</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Shopping bags</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Garment bags</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Printed ribbon</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Tissue paper</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Fabric pouches</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Hat boxes</div>
                </li>
                <li class="markets-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/icons/bakery.png" class="img-responsive"><br>
                        Bakery and Confectionery
                    </a>                    
                    <div class="submarket">Cake boxes</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Specialist cake bags </div>
                    <div class="submarket">Bakery goods boxes</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Printed ribbon</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Cake  trays</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Tin packaging</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Luxury confectionery boxes</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Bags</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Sticky labels</div>
                </li>
                <li class="markets-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/icons/cosmetics.png" class="img-responsive"><br>
                        Cosmetics
                    </a>
                    <div class="submarket">Glassware</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Custom retail packaging</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Luxury boxes</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Bags</div>
                    <div class="submarket">Specialist perfume labels</div>
                </li>
                <li class="markets-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/icons/goods.png" class="img-responsive"><br>
                        Place for your sector
                    </a>
                    <div class="submarket">As trendsetters and true connoisseurs of packaging  we are always excited to explore new 
                    grounds across the industry. If your sector or  a product you are looking for, is not listed, please do get in touch. </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>          
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: are you sure? it works perfect for me on Chrome Version 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit)

Comment: my version is 43.3.3.185, and I have a bug...

Comment: have you tried to reproduce on Safari? (also webkit based, though, Chrome had moved to another web engine but still inherits from webkit)

Comment: at safari this plugin totaly does not working...

Comment: ok i saw the exact problem you're talking about... debugging...

Comment: i see that this post is duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099838/can-anybody-help-me-with-jquery-animations --- and this one got answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that even though you set `$('.markets-item:not(.active):last').one(animatedend)` on only one element, it is fired multiple times. That could be because `animatedend` represents a collection of events:

> webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend

If you view the console in [this modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vj4tu1z/1/) you will see that a `notActivedItemsCount` I've set up goes below zero. That means that `$('.markets-item:not(.active):last').one(animatedend)` is called more times than it should.

You do have an `.animate()` in the same block of code, so it is unclear if that is causing a race condition because we can't guarantee that `$('.markets-item:not(.active):last')` - the last element in the list - is *also* the last element to finish animation.

In this [second modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vj4tu1z/2/), I've added

```
notActivedItems.unbind(animatedend);
```

inside your `.one(animatedend, function() {` block which will guarantee that this block of code will only be executed once.

Here is a working, modified version of your original fiddle with that one line added: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3zodcqmd/)

Comment: My pleasure. Nice demo BTW.